# How to apply flatMap() to implement the following logic with Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap

I have the following for loop:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

for (Team team : teams) {
   ArrayList<TeamPlayer> teamPlayers = team.getTeamPlayers();
   for (teamPlayer player : teamPlayers) {
       players.add(new Player(player.getName, player.getPosition());
   }
}
```

and I'm trying to convert it to a Stream:

```
List<Player> players = teams.forEach(t -> t.getTeamPlayers()
    .forEach(p -> players.add(new Player(p.getName(), p.getPosition())))
);
```

But I'm getting a compilation error:

```
variable 'players' might not have been initialized
```

Why is this happening? Maybe there's an alternative way to create the stream, I was thinking of using `flatMap` but not sure how to apply it.

Comment: could you add full code with stream, is `List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();` exists in second case?

Comment: if i add `List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();` the i got: Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final

Comment: Your Team and Player hierarchy does not make sense based on your loop structure.  Please include the classes that define `Team, Player, and TeamPlayers`.   This should be a [mre] that executes and demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand that Streams **don't** act like Loops.

Hence, don't try to mimic a loop. Examine the tools offered by the API. Operation `forEach()` is there for special cases when you need to perform *side-effects*, **not** in order to accumulate elements from the stream into a Collection.

***Note:** with* `teams.forEach()` *you're not actually using a stream, but method* `Iterable.forEach()` *which is available with every implementation of* `Iterable`.

To perform reduction on streams, we have several specialized operations like `collect`, `reduce`, etc. (*for more information refer to the [API documentation - Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction)*).

[`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) operation is meant to perform mutable reduction. You can use to collect the data into a list by providing built-in Collector `Collectors.toList()` as an argument. And since Java 16 operation `toList()` was introduced into API, which is implemented on top of the `toArray()` operation and performs better than namesake collector (*therefore it's a preferred option if your JDK version allows you to use it*).

> I was thinking of using `flatMap` but not sure how to apply it.

Operation `flatMap()` is meant to perform *one-to-many* transformations. It expects a *Function* which takes a stream element and generates a Stream of the resulting type, elements of the generated stream become a replacement for the initial element.

***Note:** that general approach to writing streams to use as fewer operations as possible (because one of the main advantages that Functional programming brings to Java is simplicity). For that reason, applying* `flatMap()` *when a stream element produces a Collection in a single step is idiomatic, since it's sorter than performing* `map().flatMap()` *in two steps.*

That's how implementation might look like:

```
List<Team> teams = List.of();

List<Player> players = teams.stream()                // Stream<Team>
    .flatMap(team -> team.getTeamPlayers().stream()) // Stream<Player>
    .map(player -> new Player(player.getName(), player.getPosition()))
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: @user16320675 Are you aware that a list produced by [`Collects.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) is **not** guaranteed to be modifiable ? Quote: *"There are **no guarantees** on the type, **mutability**, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned"*

Comment: @user16320675 Your comment is ambiguous and might be read as `toList()` is unmodifiable apposed to `Collectors.toList()` (just in case, it's a common missconception).

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the answer of [Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74692687/15162525), but with method reference.

```java
final var players = teams.stream()
                .map(Team::getTeamPlayers)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(p -> new Player(p.getName(), p.getPosition()))
                .toList();
```

If your `Player` class has a factory method like (depending on the relation between `Player` and `TeamPlayer`:

```java
public static Player fromTeamPlayer(final TeamPlayer teamPlayer) {
    return new Player(teamPlayer.getName(), teamPlayer.getPosition());
}
```

You could further reduce it to:

```java
final var players = teams.stream()
                .map(Team::getTeamPlayers)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(Player::fromTeamPlayer)
                .toList();
```